# Xcode adds comment characters in the first column?

Tags: xcode

Whenever I use the Xcode keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> for commenting line(s) of code in a Swift/Objective-C source file, the `//` characters are always placed in the first column. I would much prefer it be at the current indentation.

I guess this is a personal preference, but does anyone know if there's config for it:

For e.g., If I have this code snippet:

```
    ...
    print("something")
    ...
```

and I invoke the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> with the caret positioned on the line containing `print` statement, I get:

```
    ...
//      print("something")
    ...
```

I'd prefer the following behavior instead:

```
    ...
    print("something")
    ...
```

I invoke the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> with the caret positioned on the line containing `print` statement, I should get:

```
    ...
    // print("something")
    ...
```

I guess this is a personal preference, but does anyone know if there's configuration for it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Comment Here](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/comment-here/id1406737173?mt=12) extension. After downloading:

1. Restart Xcode
2. Go to Xcode -> preferences -> key bindings
3. Search for "Comment Selection" and remove the key binding for it
4. Search for "Comment Here" and add the key binding "command /" for
   the toggle comments option.
5. Your comments are now pretty :)

Comment: This works! I don't understand why comments in Xcode are formatted so weird.

Answer (score 1):

Using the mentioned keyboard shortcut, the comment character `//` always appear in the first column irrespective of the indentation level. There is no built-in mechanism to configure this behaviour.

Comment: I want to accept this answer, after all you say it with such an authoritative air, but how do we know you're correct? I guess this is sort of a null-hypothesis issue. How can you link me to docs that prove you're right? The docs just won't say how to do it if it's not possible...

Comment: I have had the exact same query for a long time. From the official documents, I couldn't find anything other than the shortcut. What I learnt is that the indentation behaviour doesn't work this way with comments. Also, tempering with the comment line indentation leads to other undesired effects. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400879/xcode-comment-uncomment-issue) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179148/how-can-i-make-xcode-indent-characters-when-i-set-a-line-to-commented).